# Why are my C++WinRT includes not working?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

So I recently tried to set up the environment to develop UWP apps, and installed VS community 2019 16.5.3
Here are my selected components:

[UWP development workload and Desktop development with C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKnla.png)

I also installed the VSIX extension from the VS market place.

[When I create a new Windows Console App(C++WinRT) this is my main and you can see the error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc3y4.png)

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2019. I have the proper Windows 10 SDK version + I also enabled developer mode in Windows settings. Im on Windows 10 1909 build 18363.720

The includes are in 'pch.h' by default.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], and please post code and error messages as **text**, not images. This includes the (relevant) contents of your *pch.h* file. At a guess, your includes aren't found, because those are generated files. You'll have to build the project at least once to get them generated.

Comment: Thank you I tried building the project, then running it and it worked.